# Sierpiński Constant

Tags: number-theory, analysis

If we note $r_2(n)$ the number of representations of n as sum of two square we have that
$\sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{r_2(k)}{k} = K + \pi \ln(n) + O(n^{\frac{1}{2}})$ in $+ \infty$

(the number $K$ is a constant called Sierpiński constant)

I search a complete proof of this result. Or any document/link/book to prove this.

Someone can help me  ?

Thank you

Comment: This is $(33)$ [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SumofSquaresFunction.html), with references below.

Comment: Thank you but among the 39 references in this article, which one correspond to the proof of the result  ?